# How to Stretch an image by dragging its sides in Adobe flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

I want to develop a hair style app in adobe flex. In that ,the wigs should be placed in right position.
So i want to adjust the wigs in x and y directions.

Does anybody know how to stretch an image in x and y direction?

App Reference:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.MagicMirrorFree&feature=search_result

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the very good [Transform Tool](http://www.senocular.com/?entry=372).  I've used it myself and can highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

you can put re-size handlers on pretty much anything, for example like this:
http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2009/03/resizable-containers.html

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop it by yourself, you may have a look on the transformation matrix class.  There is a very good tutorial about this:
http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/

Otherwise, you may use existing library:

1. as Richie_W mention, Transform Tool is a good one, the following is Transform Tool Developer Guide:
   http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformtool/

   The following link is Transform Tool using in flex:
   http://www.sephiroth.it/weblog/archives/2007/07/transformtool_modification.php
2. TransformManager is also another one:http://www.greensock.com/transformmanageras3/
   but this is a commercial one.